# Flutter: bottom center widget in stack

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I wanna achieve like this pic. to simplify I created a stack that contains two Containers. i want to bottom center the small container using Align widget but its not working! it is always remaining at the top

```
Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 170,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(0))),
                  // child: Image.network(tutorImage),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 58):

You can use the Positioned.fill with Align inside a Stack:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 170,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(0))),
          // child: Image.network(tutorImage),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: This worked for me in a situation. I still seek the understanding of "Align inside Positioned.fill" concept.

Comment: Worked like a charm here too, but I'm still wondering why I need an Align and a Positioned.fill, when simply using a Positioned(bottom: 0) should do the job, but it turns out it doesn't...

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 170,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(0))),
          // child: Image.network(tutorImage),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: -30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: its centered correctly, but there is a problem with this implementation. i want to overlap the small container like in the image above. when i set top : 50 or greater the container squeezes!

Comment: @M.Ali You do not need to use top. I will edit my answer to show you how you can do it.

Comment: remember the Widgets visible outside of stack's max size does not register the Gestures. Avoid if you need some GestureDetectors on Overflowing Widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrap your container into a Column and use axis align properties.

```
Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, In my test this line causes bad behavior
              height: 170,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(0))),
              // child: Image.network(tutorImage),
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, // start at end/bottom of column 
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
              children: <Widget>[
                Center( //  center in horizontal axis
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: why should i use column here? 
what is the problem with align widget?

Comment: To be sincere I've never used Align widgets. I always make alignment with axis properties and Flex factors. Anyway after your question update now it's more clear what kind of effect you want and the column approach will not work in this case. Sorry about it.