# Alignment with Stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

#### Project

Hi,
I was trying to align some widgets inside a Stack in Flutter. My end result was something like:
[image]

I know that this can be easily achieved with a Row but I want to animate the position ot the two children so I'm forced to use stack.

My problem is simple:

#### Example code

```
return Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: _buildSign(),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: _buildSign(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This will not render as I expected. No matter what I put in the `alignment` field: `Alignment.centerRight` and `Alignment.centerLeft` will always place the child to the center left.

The problem is solved only if I give a fixed width to the wrapping container. Now I understand why this happend but what if I want the container to be the size of his childrens? Label is a dynamic text so his width is unpredictable for me

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `"I know that this can be easily achieved with a Row but I want to animate the position ot the two children so I'm forced to use stack."` so use [Flow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flow-class.html) widget instead (click on the demo movie to see how it works)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hy justAnotherOverflowUser,

In your case, you have to use `Positioned` Widget inside `Stack` Widget,
it will give you what you want.

as example:

```dart
Positioned(
  left: 20.0,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.monetization_on, 
    size: 36.0, 
    color: const Color.fromRGBO(218, 165, 32, 1.0)
  )
)
```

Comment: I was thinking about that. But my animation has to swap the position of the two element. Plus sign have to animate from left : 20 to end 20. To my knowledge this is not possible unless you know the width of the widget

Comment: the correct answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054721/flutter-bottom-center-widget-in-stack

Comment: When you work with rtl and ltr, AlignmentDirectional comes in handy, so using Positioned instead is not a really good solution

Answer (score 18):

The more flexible way for such alignment is to wrap `Align` with `Positioned.fill`
The original answer was posted here [Flutter: bottom center widget in stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054721/flutter-bottom-center-widget-in-stack)

```
return Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
       child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: _buildSign(),
      ),),
      Positioned.fill(
       child:Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: _buildSign(),
      ),),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wrapping each `Stack` element with a `Row` and setting the `mainAxisAlignment` property:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            "Center",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text(
            "Right",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
)
```